# Change linear-gradient background on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's assume I have an array with the following colors below, how I make the colors to be alternating when I click on something using jQuery?

```
var colors = {          
    orange: { 
          color1: '#FE6442',
          color2: '#F53A45'
      },
      purple: {
          color1: '#B051F7',
          color2: '#9647F0'
      },
      blue: {
          color1: '#006DD9',
          color2: '#005BB7'
      }, 
}
```

I want to change the `linear-gradient` background to the two colors of each array and that the colors change in order with each click.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post code.

Comment: start looking at (1) how to listen to click event (2) how to change CSS with JS/jQuery (3) how to read an array ...

Comment: @HenslerSoftware Sorry. I'm new with jQuery.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I did some research but no success.:/

Comment: The 3 points I listed are very common and you can find them in any only tutorials, simply google them. I cannot get convinced that you found nothing about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
const colors = {
  orange: {
    color1: '#FE6442',
    color2: '#F53A45'
  },
  purple: {
    color1: '#B051F7',
    color2: '#9647F0'
  },
  blue: {
    color1: '#006DD9',
    color2: '#005BB7'
  },
};

let clickIndex = 1;
$('.grd-switcher').on('click', function() {
  $(this).css({'background': `linear-gradient(${Object.values(colors[Object.keys(colors)[clickIndex]]).join(', ')})`});
  
  if (clickIndex === Object.keys(colors).length-1) {
    clickIndex = 0;
  } else {
    clickIndex++;
  }
});
```

```css
.grd-switcher {
  background: linear-gradient(#FE6442, #F53A45);
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
}
.grd-switcher:before {
  content: 'Click Me!';
  display: block;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="grd-switcher">

</div>
```

but that said, your `colors` variable is not an array but an object, it would be easier to handle if it actually was an array, like this:

```js
const colors = [
  // orange
  {
    color1: '#FE6442',
    color2: '#F53A45'
  },
  // purple
  {
    color1: '#B051F7',
    color2: '#9647F0'
  },
  // blue
  {
    color1: '#006DD9',
    color2: '#005BB7'
  },
];

let clickIndex = 1;
$('.grd-switcher').on('click', function() {
  $(this).css({'background': `linear-gradient(${Object.values(colors[clickIndex]).join(', ')})`});
  
  if (clickIndex === colors.length-1) {
    clickIndex = 0;
  } else {
    clickIndex++;
  }
});
```

```css
.grd-switcher {
  background: linear-gradient(#FE6442, #F53A45);
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
}
.grd-switcher:before {
  content: 'Click Me!';
  display: block;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="grd-switcher">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hard-coding your colors into the JS, I would store them as CSS classes and just cycle through the classes. This should help making your code more maintainable due to [separating concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). It also allows you to be more flexible, not restricting you to only using 2-color linear gradients.

```js
// Since the styling is stored in the CSS,
// we just need a list of CSS classes we will
// cycle through. Editing this list is made
// simpler and less error prone than copy/pasting whole
// objects around.
var colors = [
  'orange',
  'purple',
  'blue',
  'hal',
  'rainbow',
  'cat',
];
var currentColor = 0;

// cache the #target element in a variable
// so we don't have to query the document
// every time we want to use it.
var target = jQuery('#target');

target.click(function (evt) {
  // increment our counter
  currentColor += 1;
  // use the remainder operator to roll back to 0
  // if we reached the end of the list
  currentColor %= colors.length;
  // update the element's class property,
  // removing the old class and adding the new class
  target.prop('class', colors[currentColor]);
});
```

```css
.orange {
     background: linear-gradient(#FE6442, #F53A45);
}
.purple {
     background: linear-gradient(#B051F7, #9647F0);
}
.blue {
     background: linear-gradient(#006DD9, #005BB7);
}

.hal {
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255,0,0,1) 34%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 78%);
}

.rainbow {
  background: rgb(195,34,34);
  background: linear-gradient(54deg, rgba(195,34,34,1) 0%, rgba(200,198,35,1) 20%, rgba(54,206,36,1) 40%, rgba(37,76,203,1) 60%, rgba(161,88,166,1) 80%, rgba(253,45,45,1) 100%);
}

.cat {
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/200/125");
 }

#target {
  height: 125px;
  width: 200px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: #000 1px 1px 1px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="target" class="orange">Click me</button>
```

One thing to note, the `.prop` method will wipe out all of the `class` properties on the element. If you need to have classes other than the color classes on the element, you need to be more selective about what we remove. The following version uses `.removeClass()` and `.addClass()` instead of `.prop()`:

```js
var colors = [
  'orange',
  'purple',
  'blue',
];
var currentColor = 0;

var target = jQuery('#target');

target.click(function (evt) {
  // remove the old class before incrementing
  target.removeClass(colors[currentColor]);
  currentColor += 1;
  currentColor %= colors.length;
  // add the new class
  target.addClass(colors[currentColor]);
});
```

```css
.orange {
     background: linear-gradient(#FE6442, #F53A45);
}
.purple {
     background: linear-gradient(#B051F7, #9647F0);
}
.blue {
     background: linear-gradient(#006DD9, #005BB7);
}

.upsidedown {
  transform: rotate(0.5turn);
}

#target {
  height: 125px;
  width: 200px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: #000 1px 1px 1px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="target" class="orange upsidedown">Click me</button>
```

If you were not using jQuery, you could use the methods of [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) manipulate the classes in a similar way.

### More reading

- [Remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder)
- [Remainder assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Remainder_assignment)
- [Addition assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment_2)
- [`jQuery.prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)
- [`jQuery.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)
- [`jQuery.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/)